# Error storybook TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Tags: vuejs3, storybook

I'm using the storybook with vue 3 and I started getting this error, is it happening to anyone else?

```
ERR!  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
```

This is my package .json

```
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/theming": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/vue3": "^6.4.22",
```

Comment: Ar you using `@storybook/builder-vite`? I've got the same problem, and for now figured only that `.vue` files are not processed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are using `@storybook/builder-vite`, since I had this problem only with this particular builder.

This error is probably related to you using `vue-class-component` which is not well supported by the `vue-docgen` plugin.

Related issues:

- https://github.com/storybookjs/builder-vite/issues/148
- https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/14052

In the second issue there is a workaround given:

```js
import {Vue, Options} from 'vue-property-decorator'

// Create an alias for Options
const Component = Options;

// Instead of @Options do @Component
@Component({
  name: 'Icon'
})
export default class Icon extends Vue {
  // ...
}
```

But I had not used it so I cannot confirm that it really works. You can also entirely disable the docgen plugin in the `finalVite` method:

```js
async viteFinal(storybookConfig, { configType }) {
    const { config } = await loadConfigFromFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../vite.config.ts"))

    // remove vue-docgen plugin as it causes problems
    storybookConfig.plugins = storybookConfig.plugins.filter(plugin => plugin.name !== 'vue-docgen')

    // return the customized config
    return mergeConfig(storybookConfig, {
        base: '/dist/',
        resolve: config.resolve,
        // has-symbols requires global to be available
        define: { ...config.define, global: {} },
        // remove duplicated vue plugin
        plugins: config.plugins.filter(plugin => plugin.name !== 'vite:vue'),
    });
},
```

This solved issue for me. You should also check version of the storybook - I was not able to run vue3 with vite on the 6.5 version.